# Ngrx handle API failure

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

This question concerns the example provided by ngrx [example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app) (I didn't know if I can post this to their Github page or not...)

So when creating a new project I wanted to follow the best guidelines, that's why I'm checking the example app as a reference. In the application when for example they try to delete a book entity the do the following :

1. Component dispatches a request with the action 'removeBook' and 'book' object as payload (selected-book-page.component.ts:40)
2. The effect handles that and if success it calls the 'removeBookSuccess' action which will remove the book from the store (collection.effects.ts:65)

Now the second case is when it fails it will call 'removeBookFailure' also with book object and actually that action will be handled exactly like 'addBookSuccess'

```
on(
    CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess,
    CollectionApiActions.removeBookFailure,
    (state, { book }) => {
      if (state.ids.indexOf(book.id) > -1) {
        return state;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        ids: [...state.ids, book.id],
      };
    }
  ),
```

Do we really need to do that? I mean the book in question was never removed to begin with. Or is there something I'm missing here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wonder if this was originally intended as an optimistic delete with `CollectionApiActions.removeBook` removing the book (reducer)?

Comment: That would be my guess too, but they are not removing id from state, only after success..

Comment: @fzwael I've created issue on github. Just let me know if you want to do the PR (i recommend doing this if you haven't before) once core team decide which way round it should be

Comment: @AndrewAllen yes I can create a PR, but shouldn't we check with the core team if this is really necessary ?

Comment: @fzwael issue asks this in the title -  https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2417 `is removeBookFailure reducer correct?` All tests pass with line removed...

Comment: Actually yest, because in the next line there is a condition `if (state.ids.indexOf(book.id) > -1)` so this would be true and we won't add another book. But problem is that this would be always true so there is no need for the code (even though there is no problem when we keep it)

Answer (score 1):

It might seem weird, but it serves API failures.
What I do expect, and what is missing, is the removal of the book when the `removeBook` action is dispatched.

If the API call succeeds, everything is already handled correctly - but when it fails we should revert the removal of the book.

Comment: I agree, but if you check the process in the example application in no case there was a removal of the book itself since we call the API first then decide if we remove the book from the store ( when success ) so it looks to me that the action to put back an existing item is redundant.
Anyways it's not really a bug just a bit confusing from workflow point of view.